# Any way to apply an overlay color effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, colors, filter, overlay, effect

I want to do something like overlay a grey layout over my website to get the chance to apply a color effect like "Instagram" or something like that in the entire website. I was trying setting all elements opacity but body to .9  and setting the body background with the color that I want to get in my website. The result is not satisfactory with this approach.

I can not put an overlay layer to my website because I want to be able to interact with te website, so... anyone has an idea to get this kind of effect?

Maybe using an overlay and tracking de clicks with jQuery and trying to apply the click on the underneath layers? Anyone has tried?

Comment: It's possible to grey everything out using `canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), but you have to check compatibility. It is not well supported by every browser but if it's for an internal project or anything you have controle on, this could totally be a solution :

```
#overlay{
    position : fixed;
    top :0;
    left:0;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background-color : rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6yJvw/

Answer (score 0):

You can put an overlay and still interact with the page:

```
.overlay {
z-index:1000;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
background:#000;
opacity:0.45;
-moz-opacity:0.45;
filter:alpha(opacity=45);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lassebjensen/zc9j3/4/